# What is Nirtzah?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

In every one of the 15 steps one is supposed (according to Halacha) to either do something, eat something or say something.

For example,

1. Kadesh - one must do Kiddush - Biblical/Rabbinic.
2. Urchatz - one must wash his hands - Rabbinic
3. Karpas - dip vegetableinto salt water - (old standing) custom.

etc.
However, what exactly is the Halachic requirements involved in Nirtzah. All the more so, where in the [Hagadda of the Baal HaTanya](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10502&st=&pgnum=47), the only thing that comes after the fourth cup is Leshana Habaah.

What exactly is Nirtzah then?

Comment: The Rambam doesn't have Nirtza at all. Just the fourth cup and that's it. See his haggadah [here](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3510.htm)

Comment: I think Hallel Nirtza might just be one step. Like Shulchan Orech. Some Rishonim had mnemonics like Yehallel BeDitza. This may be analogous. (Possibly we can argue that Nirtza is saying Hallel HaGadol after Hallel. This depends a lot on the formulations of Rishonim regarding the fifth cup of wine. I'd be curious to do more research about that.) What's clear though is many rishonim had various mnemonics for the 'steps' of the seder (Avudraham lists like 6-7 ones that were in use). Don't get too attached to the common one printed today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Shalom's answer.

From [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/269921/jewish/Nirtzah.htm)

> **Nirtzah**
>   **Acceptance**
>
> The steps of the Seder have been integrated into our consciousness and accepted. Now we pause, take a deep breath, and reflect on our experience: We examined our personal challenges through the slavery of our ancestors, and we achieved a personal freedom by reliving the Exodus. We completed our part in good faith; the rest is up to you-know-Who.

Also from [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/wizard_cdo/aid/117126/jewish/15-Accepted.htm)

> ...And now, let Him do what He has promised to do: A re-run. A modern exodus of liberation. Starring us. With lots of miracles. But this time, forever.

---

[The Bnei Yissachar has another explanation](http://books.google.com/books?id=RZTN12uaEKQC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&source=bl&ots=fZZVwWGpeQ&sig=xYWN6M1FMpTkf058LD6KWHQtuwc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5aI9T8amGaKs2gX51eC0CA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBTgK)

These are only excerpts. Check the links for more in-depth coverage.

Answer (score 3):

A conclusion by which we hope that our Seder was "acceptable"/"desirable" to G-d.

Answer (score -2):

Triumph I have great confidence that our effort on this night which were offered with sincerity and prayers for positive connection and transference to our families were recognized and accepted in the spirit in which they are intended.

Comment: What???????????

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I think this is the 'message' of Nirtza